# Is there an easy way within Laravel to update a one-to-one relationship and have it update the old as well as the new?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel app at the moment to manage cameras and lenses. Each camera can have one lens, and vice versa.
The problem is, when I change the lens on the camera by setting camera_id in the lens table, the old value remains next to the old lens.
Example: Lens 1 belongs to Camera 1 - camera_id on Lens 1 = 1, camera_id on Lens 2 = 0 Lens 1 is changed to belong to Camera 2 - camera_id on both Lens 1 & 2 is now 1
I've tried multiple ways to make it change camera_id for Lens 1 to zero because, otherwise, when it goes to grab the lens for that camera, it grabs the first of many, which is wrong.
I've been Googling unsuccessfully for an hour or so and found information on associate(), which apparently changes a one-to-one relationship: it still does the same thing.
Function that makes the change:

```
function changeLensOnCamera() {
$camera = Camera::find($_POST['camera_id']);
$lens   = Lens::find($_POST['lens_select']);
$lens->camera()->associate($camera);
$lens->save();

return Redirect::to('cameras');
}
```

Models:

```
class Lens extends Eloquent
{
use SoftDeletingTrait;

protected $table = 'lens';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $fillable = array('camera_id');

public function camera()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Camera');
}

public function manufacturer()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('LensManufacturer');
}
}
?>

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Camera extends Eloquent
{
use SoftDeletingTrait;

protected $table = 'cameras';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $fillable = array('lens_id');

public function lens()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Lens');
}
}
?>
```

I've tried having:

```
Lens::find($_POST['lens_select'])->camera->update(array('camera_id' => 0));
```

as well, but it doesn't seem to actually make the change in the database. Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: Don't use POST data directly. Not only is it vulnerable, Laravel even allows you to access request data via a Request class, so you have no excuse.

Comment: I know :( I was at the stage where I just wanted it to work, and have been back through it and overhauled that aspect to pull from Request/Input and  check inputs are numeric

Answer (score 0):

Use this to clear the lens associated with the camera:

```
$camera->lens()->update(array('camera_id' => 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you have your tables set up you actually have one to many relationship on cameras and lenses.  Technically, you can have multiple lenses belonging to one camera if the camera_id points to same same camera on multiple lens rows.

What you should probably do is add lens_id column to the camera table instead, and relate cameras to lenses through that column. That way, it is only possible to have one lens related to the specific camera.